# How do I find market equilibrium with two market actors (firm setting price and government setting excise tax) in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to find equilibrium in a market with given demand function, a firm maximizing its profits and the government setting excise tax to maximize tax income. I wrote code for the maximization problems the firm and government use to maximize their profit/taxes. Now I'm not sure what the next step is to find the equilibrium. Can anyone help me with the next step?

I think I have to define a fixed point and use that to solve for equilibrium. In the classes I had at my university we only did this for cournot equilibrium with multiple firms. I'm not sure how to do this in this situation with a firm and government setting excise tax. Later I want to add a second product (substite or complement) to the model, but I need to figure out how to solve for equilibrium price and excise tax in this more simple model based on best responses first.

This is the code I have written, I'm looking for the next step to solve for equilibrium price and excise tax based on their best responses.

```
from scipy import stats, optimize

alpha1 = 10
beta1 = -0.5
c1 = 0.5

def Q1(P1,t1):
    return alpha1+beta1*P1*(1+t1)

def profits1(P1,t1,c1):
    return Q1(P1,t1)*(P1-c1)

def taxes(t1,P1):
    return Q1(P1,t1)*P1*t1

def reactionfirm1(t1,c1):
    P1 = optimize.fminbound(lambda x: -profits1(x,t1,c1),0,100)
    return P1

def reactiongovernment1(P1):
    t1 = optimize.fminbound(lambda x: -taxes(x,P1),0,100)
    return t1
```

Solving this with pen and paper gives t1=3.73 and P1=2.36 (both rounded).

To solve it with pen and paper, I first find the best responses of the firm and government. For the firm the best response is found by taking the first derivative of the profit function with respect to P1, putting this equal to 0 and writing P1 as a function of t1. Which gives:

P1 = (10.25+0.25t1)/(1+t)

Similarly, for the best response of the government can be found by taking the first derivative of tax income with respect to t1, putting this equal to 0 and writing t1 as a function of P1, which gives:

t1 = 10/P1 -0.5

To find P1 and t1, you either plug in t1 into P1 or P1 into t1 and solve it.

So I plugged in P1 into t1 to get:

t1 = (10+10t)/(10.25+0.25t) -0.5

Which gives t1 = 3.73

and by plugging t1 = 3.73 in the best response of the firms I get P1 = 2.36

What I was hoping to do with Python is computing and solving the best responses of the firm and government to find t1 and P1. Because I want to expand the model, which makes it more complicated to solve by pen and paper. Also, by having it in python it will be easier to change the paramaters alpha1, beta1 and c1 to see how the optimum P1 and t1 change.

Comment: You will need to know and provide the algorithm you actually want to implement to get help for this. Having test data with your expected output is also going to get you a lot better help.

Comment: @KenSyme Thank you for your feedback.

I have edited my original question to explain how I solve it by pen and paper and what solution I get (which output is expected). I hope this clears up what I want to do in Python. The problem is I'm not sure how to code this in Python so I also do not know the algorithm.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure how to tackle this off the bat. Two options spring to mind - write another two functions for calculating the derivative of the profit and tax functions you have, then use them to solve your problem. Or look at something like tensorflow or pytorch, which if you can write your algorithm in their structures, they will do automatic differentiation and optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

I used this python code in my thesis to find the Cournot equilibrium (quantities that maximize profits). I also leave you the code that I used to check for concavity. I do this for 8 firms, but you can collapse it to two. Also the costs are more complex, you can take out the letters and keep just the variable cost since the letters represent linear reduction in costs:

```
import sympy as sym
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Define symbols
q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, a1, b2, c3, d4, e1, e5, e6, e7, e8, f2, f5, f6, f7, f8, g3, g5, g6, g7, g8, h4, h5, h6, h7, h8, n = sym.symbols('q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 q6 q7 q8 a1 b2 c3 d4 e1 e5 e6 e7 e8 f2 f5 f6 f7 f8 g3 g5 g6 g7 g8 h4 h5 h6 h7 h8 n')

# Define parameters
#alpha = sym.Symbol('alpha')
#cost = sym.Symbol('cost')
#s = sym.Symbol('s')
#each time you change network also change prices, costs, utility
alpha=10
cost=5
s=0.8


# Define profit functions
P1 = alpha - q1 - s*q2 - s*q8
P2 = alpha - q2 - s*q3 - s*q1
P3 = alpha - q3 - s*q4 - s*q2
P4 = alpha - q4 - s*q5 - s*q3
P5 = alpha - q5 - s*q6 - s*q4
P6 = alpha - q6 - s*q7 - s*q5
P7 = alpha - q7 - s*q8 - s*q6
P8 = alpha - q8 - s*q1 - s*q7



C1 = cost - a1 - n*e1
C2 = cost - b2 - n*f2
C3 = cost - c3 - n*g3
C4 = cost - d4 - n*h4
C5 = cost - e5 - e1 - n*a1 - e6 - e7 - e8 - n*f5 - n*f6 - n*f7 - n*f8 - n*g5 - n*g6 - n*g7 - n*g8 - n*h5 - n*h6 - n*h7 - n*h8
C6 = cost - f6 - f2 - n*b2 - f5 - f7 - f8 - n*e5 - n*e6 - n*e7 - n*e8 - n*g5 - n*g6 - n*g7 - n*g8 - n*h5 - n*h6 - n*h7 - n*h8
C7 = cost - g7 - g3 - n*c3 - g5 - g6 - g8 - n*f5 - n*f6 - n*f7 - n*f8 - n*e5 - n*e6 - n*e7 - n*e8 - n*h5 - n*h6 - n*h7 - n*h8
C8 = cost - h8 - h4 - n*d4 - h5 - h6 - h7 - n*f5 - n*f6 - n*f7 - n*f8 - n*g5 - n*g6 - n*g7 - n*g8 - n*e5 - n*e6 - n*h7 - n*e8




prof1 = (P1-C1)*q1 - 2*a1**2
prof2 = (P2-C2)*q2 - 2*b2**2
prof3 = (P3-C3)*q3 - 2*c3**2
prof4 = (P4-C4)*q4 - 2*d4**2
prof5 = (P5-C5)*q5 - 10*e1**2 - 10*e5**2 - 10*e6**2 - 10*e7**2 - 10*e8**2
prof6 = (P6-C6)*q6 - 10*f2**2 - 10*f5**2 - 10*f6**2 - 10*f7**2 - 10*f8**2
prof7 = (P7-C7)*q7 - 10*g3**2 - 10*g5**2 - 10*g6**2 - 10*g7**2 - 10*g8**2
prof8 = (P8-C8)*q8 - 10*h4**2 - 10*h5**2 - 10*h6**2 - 10*h7**2 - 10*h8**2




# Take derivatives
dq1 = sym.diff(prof1, q1)
dq2 = sym.diff(prof2, q2)
dq3 = sym.diff(prof3, q3)
dq4 = sym.diff(prof4, q4)
dq5 = sym.diff(prof5, q5)
dq6 = sym.diff(prof6, q6)
dq7 = sym.diff(prof7, q7)
dq8 = sym.diff(prof8, q8)


# Set derivatives to 0 and solve for q1, q2, q3
soln = sym.solve((dq1, dq2, dq3, dq4, dq5, dq6, dq7, dq8), (q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8))

# Print optimal values of q1, q2, q3
print("Optimal value of q1:", soln[q1])
print("Optimal value of q2:", soln[q2])
print("Optimal value of q3:", soln[q3])
print("Optimal value of q4:", soln[q4])
print("Optimal value of q5:", soln[q5])
print("Optimal value of q6:", soln[q6])
print("Optimal value of q7:", soln[q7])
print("Optimal value of q8:", soln[q8])


p1 = P1.subs({q1: soln[q1], q2: soln[q2], q3: soln[q3], q4: soln[q4], q5: soln[q5], q6: soln[q6], q7: soln[q7], q8: soln[q8]})
p2 = P2.subs({q1: soln[q1], q2: soln[q2], q3: soln[q3], q4: soln[q4], q5: soln[q5], q6: soln[q6], q7: soln[q7], q8: soln[q8]})
p3 = P3.subs({q1: soln[q1], q2: soln[q2], q3: soln[q3], q4: soln[q4], q5: soln[q5], q6: soln[q6], q7: soln[q7], q8: soln[q8]})
p4 = P4.subs({q1: soln[q1], q2: soln[q2], q3: soln[q3], q4: soln[q4], q5: soln[q5], q6: soln[q6], q7: soln[q7], q8: soln[q8]})
p5 = P5.subs({q1: soln[q1], q2: soln[q2], q3: soln[q3], q4: soln[q4], q5: soln[q5], q6: soln[q6], q7: soln[q7], q8: soln[q8]})
p6 = P6.subs({q1: soln[q1], q2: soln[q2], q3: soln[q3], q4: soln[q4], q5: soln[q5], q6: soln[q6], q7: soln[q7], q8: soln[q8]})
p7 = P7.subs({q1: soln[q1], q2: soln[q2], q3: soln[q3], q4: soln[q4], q5: soln[q5], q6: soln[q6], q7: soln[q7], q8: soln[q8]})
p8 = P8.subs({q1: soln[q1], q2: soln[q2], q3: soln[q3], q4: soln[q4], q5: soln[q5], q6: soln[q6], q7: soln[q7], q8: soln[q8]})


co1 = C1.subs({q1: soln[q1], q2: soln[q2], q3: soln[q3], q4: soln[q4], q5: soln[q5], q6: soln[q6], q7: soln[q7], q8: soln[q8]})
co2 = C2.subs({q1: soln[q1], q2: soln[q2], q3: soln[q3], q4: soln[q4], q5: soln[q5], q6: soln[q6], q7: soln[q7], q8: soln[q8]})
co3 = C3.subs({q1: soln[q1], q2: soln[q2], q3: soln[q3], q4: soln[q4], q5: soln[q5], q6: soln[q6], q7: soln[q7], q8: soln[q8]})
co4 = C4.subs({q1: soln[q1], q2: soln[q2], q3: soln[q3], q4: soln[q4], q5: soln[q5], q6: soln[q6], q7: soln[q7], q8: soln[q8]})
co5 = C5.subs({q1: soln[q1], q2: soln[q2], q3: soln[q3], q4: soln[q4], q5: soln[q5], q6: soln[q6], q7: soln[q7], q8: soln[q8]})
co6 = C6.subs({q1: soln[q1], q2: soln[q2], q3: soln[q3], q4: soln[q4], q5: soln[q5], q6: soln[q6], q7: soln[q7], q8: soln[q8]})
co7 = C7.subs({q1: soln[q1], q2: soln[q2], q3: soln[q3], q4: soln[q4], q5: soln[q5], q6: soln[q6], q7: soln[q7], q8: soln[q8]})
co8 = C8.subs({q1: soln[q1], q2: soln[q2], q3: soln[q3], q4: soln[q4], q5: soln[q5], q6: soln[q6], q7: soln[q7], q8: soln[q8]})


Prof1 = (p1 - co1)*soln[q1] - 2*a1**2
Prof2 = (p2 - co2)*soln[q2] - 2*b2**2
Prof3 = (p3 - co3)*soln[q3] - 2*c3**2
Prof4 = (p4 - co4)*soln[q4] - 2*d4**2
Prof5 = (p5 - co5)*soln[q5] - 10*e1**2 - 10*e5**2 - 10*e6**2 - 10*e7**2 - 10*e8**2
Prof6 = (p6 - co6)*soln[q6] - 10*f2**2 - 10*f5**2 - 10*f6**2 - 10*f7**2 - 10*f8**2
Prof7 = (p7 - co7)*soln[q7] - 10*g3**2 - 10*g5**2 - 10*g6**2 - 10*g7**2 - 10*g8**2
Prof8 = (p8 - co8)*soln[q8] - 10*h4**2 - 10*h5**2 - 10*h6**2 - 10*h7**2 - 10*h8**2



#########################################################


print("Profits with optimal quantities for firm 1:", Prof1)
print("Profits with optimal quantities for firm 2:", Prof2)
print("Profits with optimal quantities for firm 3:", Prof3)
print("Profits with optimal quantities for firm 4:", Prof4)
print("Profits with optimal quantities for firm 5:", Prof5)
print("Profits with optimal quantities for firm 6:", Prof6)
print("Profits with optimal quantities for firm 7:", Prof7)
print("Profits with optimal quantities for firm 8:", Prof8)



# Compute the second derivative of the function with respect to a1, a2
f_double_prime_Prof1_a1 = Prof1.diff(a1, 2)
f_double_prime_Prof2_b2 = Prof2.diff(b2, 2)
f_double_prime_Prof3_c3 = Prof3.diff(c3, 2)
f_double_prime_Prof4_d4 = Prof4.diff(d4, 2)
f_double_prime_Prof5_e1 = Prof5.diff(e1, 2)
f_double_prime_Prof5_e5 = Prof5.diff(e5, 2)
f_double_prime_Prof5_e6 = Prof5.diff(e6, 2)
f_double_prime_Prof5_e7 = Prof5.diff(e7, 2)
f_double_prime_Prof5_e8 = Prof5.diff(e8, 2)
f_double_prime_Prof6_f2 = Prof5.diff(f2, 2)
f_double_prime_Prof6_f5 = Prof6.diff(f5, 2)
f_double_prime_Prof6_f6 = Prof6.diff(f6, 2)
f_double_prime_Prof6_f7 = Prof6.diff(f7, 2)
f_double_prime_Prof6_f8 = Prof6.diff(f8, 2)
f_double_prime_Prof7_g3 = Prof7.diff(g3, 2)
f_double_prime_Prof7_g5 = Prof7.diff(g5, 2)
f_double_prime_Prof7_g6 = Prof7.diff(g6, 2)
f_double_prime_Prof7_g7 = Prof7.diff(g7, 2)
f_double_prime_Prof7_g8 = Prof7.diff(g8, 2)
f_double_prime_Prof8_h4 = Prof8.diff(h4, 2)
f_double_prime_Prof8_h5 = Prof8.diff(h5, 2)
f_double_prime_Prof8_h6 = Prof8.diff(h6, 2)
f_double_prime_Prof8_h7 = Prof8.diff(h7, 2)
f_double_prime_Prof8_h8 = Prof8.diff(h8, 2)

# Values of n to check for concavity
n_values = np.arange(0, 1.01, 0.01)

# Check concavity for each value of n
for n_val in n_values:
    # Substitute n with the current value   .subs(n, n_val)
    f_double_prime_Prof1_a1_n = f_double_prime_Prof1_a1.subs({n: n_val})
    f_double_prime_Prof2_b2_n = f_double_prime_Prof2_b2.subs({n: n_val})
    f_double_prime_Prof3_c3_n = f_double_prime_Prof3_c3.subs({n: n_val})
    f_double_prime_Prof4_d4_n = f_double_prime_Prof4_d4.subs({n: n_val})
    f_double_prime_Prof5_e1_n = f_double_prime_Prof5_e1.subs({n: n_val})
    f_double_prime_Prof5_e5_n = f_double_prime_Prof5_e5.subs({n: n_val})
    f_double_prime_Prof5_e6_n = f_double_prime_Prof5_e6.subs({n: n_val})
    f_double_prime_Prof5_e7_n = f_double_prime_Prof5_e7.subs({n: n_val})
    f_double_prime_Prof5_e8_n = f_double_prime_Prof5_e8.subs({n: n_val})
    f_double_prime_Prof6_f2_n = f_double_prime_Prof6_f2.subs({n: n_val})
    f_double_prime_Prof6_f5_n = f_double_prime_Prof6_f5.subs({n: n_val})
    f_double_prime_Prof6_f6_n = f_double_prime_Prof6_f6.subs({n: n_val})
    f_double_prime_Prof6_f7_n = f_double_prime_Prof6_f7.subs({n: n_val})
    f_double_prime_Prof6_f8_n = f_double_prime_Prof6_f8.subs({n: n_val})
    f_double_prime_Prof7_g3_n = f_double_prime_Prof7_g3.subs({n: n_val})
    f_double_prime_Prof7_g5_n = f_double_prime_Prof7_g5.subs({n: n_val})
    f_double_prime_Prof7_g6_n = f_double_prime_Prof7_g6.subs({n: n_val})
    f_double_prime_Prof7_g7_n = f_double_prime_Prof7_g7.subs({n: n_val})
    f_double_prime_Prof7_g8_n = f_double_prime_Prof7_g8.subs({n: n_val})
    f_double_prime_Prof8_h4_n = f_double_prime_Prof8_h4.subs({n: n_val})
    f_double_prime_Prof8_h5_n = f_double_prime_Prof8_h5.subs({n: n_val})
    f_double_prime_Prof8_h6_n = f_double_prime_Prof8_h6.subs({n: n_val})
    f_double_prime_Prof8_h7_n = f_double_prime_Prof8_h7.subs({n: n_val})
    f_double_prime_Prof8_h8_n = f_double_prime_Prof8_h8.subs({n: n_val})
    # Check if the second derivatives are non-positive
    if (f_double_prime_Prof1_a1_n.is_nonpositive and f_double_prime_Prof2_b2_n.is_nonpositive
            and f_double_prime_Prof3_c3_n.is_nonpositive and f_double_prime_Prof4_d4_n.is_nonpositive
            and f_double_prime_Prof5_e1_n.is_nonpositive and f_double_prime_Prof5_e5_n.is_nonpositive
            and f_double_prime_Prof5_e6_n.is_nonpositive and f_double_prime_Prof5_e7_n.is_nonpositive
            and f_double_prime_Prof5_e8_n.is_nonpositive and f_double_prime_Prof6_f5_n.is_nonpositive
            and f_double_prime_Prof6_f2_n.is_nonpositive and f_double_prime_Prof7_g3_n.is_nonpositive
            and f_double_prime_Prof6_f6_n.is_nonpositive and f_double_prime_Prof6_f7_n.is_nonpositive
            and f_double_prime_Prof6_f8_n.is_nonpositive and f_double_prime_Prof7_g5_n.is_nonpositive
            and f_double_prime_Prof7_g6_n.is_nonpositive and f_double_prime_Prof7_g7_n.is_nonpositive
            and f_double_prime_Prof7_g8_n.is_nonpositive and f_double_prime_Prof8_h4_n.is_nonpositive
            and f_double_prime_Prof8_h5_n.is_nonpositive and f_double_prime_Prof8_h6_n.is_nonpositive
            and f_double_prime_Prof8_h7_n.is_nonpositive and f_double_prime_Prof8_h8_n.is_nonpositive):
            
         print(f"All functions are concave for n = {n_val}")
else:
         print(f"Some functions are not concave for n = {n_val}")
```